# Register a Hotkey in Powershell (C#?)

Tags: c#, powershell, registerhotkey

So with a lot of help of this nice [site](https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.RegisterHotKey)

i was able to create the following Code

```
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    namespace User32{
    public static class NativeMethods{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetLastError();
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int FormatMessage(uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource, uint dwMessageId, uint dwLanguageId, [Out]StringBuilder lpBuffer, uint nSize, IntPtr Arguments);
    }
    }
    "@ -passthru
    #Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeDefinition -PassThru
    $modifier1 = [int][System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::ControlKey
    $modifier2 = [int][System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::Menu
    $key = [int][System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::M
    $Callback = { $notifyicon1_MouseDoubleClick.Invoke() }
    
    [int]$hotkey_ID = 1

    $hotkey_registered = [User32.NativeMethods]::RegisterHotKey([System.IntPtr]::Zero, $hotkey_id, $modifier1 -bor $modifier2, $key)
    
    if (-not $hotkey_registered)
    {
        $errorCode = [User32.NativeMethods]::GetLastError()
        $errorMsg = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder(255)
        [User32.NativeMethods]::FormatMessage(0x00001000, [IntPtr]::Zero, $errorCode, 0, $errorMsg, $errorMsg.Capacity, [IntPtr]::Zero) | Out-Null
        Logline -Message "Failed to register hotkey. Error code: $errorCode Error message: $($errorMsg.ToString().Trim())"
    }
```

But all i get is an Error that says ErrorCode 1004 Invalid Attributes

i think the $modifier Variables have the wrong value but i have no clue how to fix it. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in your link to [pinvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.RegisterHotKey) (*`KeyModifiers` Enum*):

```
 if ( -not ('User32.HotKeyModifiers' -as [type]) ) {
   Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    namespace User32{
        [Flags]
        public enum HotKeyModifiers
        {
        Alt = 1,        // MOD_ALT
        Control = 2,    // MOD_CONTROL
        Shift = 4,      // MOD_SHIFT
        WindowsKey = 8, // MOD_WIN // Either WINDOWS key was held down.
                        // These keys are labeled with the Windows logo.
                        // Keyboard shortcuts that involve the WINDOWS key
                        // are reserved for use by the operating system.
        }

        public static class NativeMethods{
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

            [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern int GetLastError();

            [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern int FormatMessage(uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource, uint dwMessageId, uint dwLanguageId, [Out]StringBuilder lpBuffer, uint nSize, IntPtr Arguments);
        }
    }
"@ -passthru
#Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeDefinition -PassThru
}

if ( -not ('System.Windows.Forms.Keys' -as [type]) ) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
}
$modifier1 = [User32.HotKeyModifiers]::Control.value__    #[int][System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::ControlKey
$modifier2 = [User32.HotKeyModifiers]::WindowsKey.value__ #[int][System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::Menu
$key = [int][System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::M
$Callback = { $notifyicon1_MouseDoubleClick.Invoke() }
    
[int]$hotkey_ID = 1

$hotkey_registered = [User32.NativeMethods]::RegisterHotKey(
    [System.IntPtr]::Zero, $hotkey_id, $modifier1 -bor $modifier2, $key)
    
if (-not $hotkey_registered)
{
    $errorCode = [User32.NativeMethods]::GetLastError()
    $errorMsg = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder(255)
    [User32.NativeMethods]::FormatMessage(0x00001000, [IntPtr]::Zero, $errorCode, 0, $errorMsg, $errorMsg.Capacity, [IntPtr]::Zero) | Out-Null
    # Logline -Message
    "Failed to register hotkey. Error code: $errorCode Error message: $($errorMsg.ToString().Trim())"
}
```

**Output**:

```
.\SO\76045855.ps1
```

> ```
> IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
> -------- -------- ----                                     --------
> True     True     HotKeyModifiers                          System.Enum
> True     False    NativeMethods                            System.Object
> Failed to register hotkey. Error code: 1409 Error message: Hot key is already registered.
> ```

Hot key <kbd>WinKey</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> is already registered to *Settings* -> *Magnifier* for me…

Comment: Hi, Yes i did not see the Flags part.
this works so far and i will mark this as the correkt answer later.. a lot of thanks so far. :)

i have edited my Question with a second Part that got me stuck again. maybe you can help me out one more time? i have enough problmes with powershell as it is but now with C# in the mix i'm struggeling like....

Comment: you are right i have undon my edit. marked your answer as correct and upvoted it :)
Thanks agaiin. I will create a new Post